Hall subgroups of the symmetric group.
I am trying to prove that $S_n$, or $A_n$ (perhaps working with $A_n$ is easier because it is simple), does not have Hall subgroups (for any set with more than one prime) for n other than a prime number or 8, I have seen that this is true but I cannot find any proof, neither simple nor difficult.

There is a paper by Thompson about it, see this post.
